# How to have two functions that call each other Java

Tags: java, forward-declaration

i know we do this in C++ like this :

```
int a();
int b() { 
  return a();
}
int a() { 
  return b();
}
```

how i can do something like this in Java ?

Comment: You already did it. But note that this is an infinite loop, your computer might explode and destroy the universe.

Comment: you can do it the same way!

Comment: Same Way ..................             :-)

Comment: It's not the same way. OP should delete the first line since forward refs work in Java with no advance declaration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java you don't have to declare variables or functions before using them. Therefore:

```
int b() { return a();}
int a() { return b();}
```

Note that this will yield a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: So your name will be there in the stack trace :P

Answer (score 3):

There is no need of forward declaration, just write the functions.

Answer (score 3):

**Here it is : The dangerous code for you :**

```
public class b 
{

   Object  first()
   {
     System.out.println("i am inside first function");
     return second();
   }

   Object  second()
   {
     System.out.println(" Like i care !  i'm scared of StackOverflowError dude !!");
     return first();
   }

   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
     new b().first();
   }

}
```

Comment: @Maroun Maroun Glad you used some 47 facial muscles. 

Comment: @Batty and how is it so ?